# mysql - Test if multiple users are in the same group

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible in one query to test if a number of users are in the same group or not?

say I have an array that looks like this:

```
 $users = array(1,3,4,5);
```

I want to dynamically write a query (so that it can handle any number of users) that would essentially check if there is a group that contains all these users AND ONLY THESE USERS already in existence. If so, return the id. If not, return 0.

The table structure is as follows:

```
 groups:
      group_id

 groups_users
      user_id
      group_id
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT group_id, count(*) AS c
FROM group_users
WHERE user_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING c = ?; /* Replace ? with len($users) */
```

Assuming that `groups_users.user_id` and `groups_users.group_id` is a unique key, if this group exists, then the result of `count(*)` should be equal to `len($users)`.

Comment: Thanks! looks great. Wasn't sure how to grab the same conversations for multiples like that.

Comment: Yes indeed, using `HAVING`, which would save you looking the result for every group in your php code.

Comment: Can you give an exmple with "HAVING" ?

Comment: Seems this is not 100% because if I pass in 2 people that are in the same group and a third who is not a part of that group it still returns true.

Comment: Yes, as I said before, without the `HAVING` you have to check on each line of the result if the second column is equal to `len($users)` in your php code.